# NextSTEP（UNIX系）　マウス　加速度設定

Tags: unix

Next STEP（UNIX系）でマウスの加速度設定を行いたいのですが、どのようにすればよろしいでしょうか？宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: Preferencesアプリ内にマウスの項目ないですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。返信遅くなり、申し訳ございません。上記、速度の設定項目しかなく、必要な
加速度の設定項目はありませんでした。宜しくお願い致します。